# How to exit a route in express.js?

Tags: node.js

Right know i wrap it whole in a big if else statement because i have multiple res.render functions.

How can i do something like this, which should prevent the rest of the route to be executed:

```
if(req.params.url === undefined){
    res.render('layout');
    return;
}
```

OR:

```
if(req.params.url === undefined){
    res.render('layout');
    next();
}
```

But both of the execute the rest of the code below them, which cause Headers already sent.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
exports.activate = function(req, res){
    var hash = req.params.hash;

    if(hash === undefined){
        res.render('activation');
        next();
    } else {
           // Do stuff with hash
           res.render('activateOne', {hash: hash});
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of this, but if you just want to exit the function after your res.render() I think you can use `return`. This should prevent the rest of your current function from executing.

A simple AJAX example (I know its client side, but its an async function and should behave similar):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'www.google.com',
   type: 'POST',
   error: function () {
      console.log('failure');
      return 0;
      console.log('after return');
   }
})
```

If you try to execute this in your browsers console, you will note the 'failure' log, however it will stop before the 'after return' message.

Comment: Yes, that right. You can use return, something else was confusing me. Thanks for you answer! :)

Comment: yes it works, but what if I  want to send a message in the response, i.e. response.json({message: 'user has been created'}); I can't use in this case return.